# Get number between two numbers when input is percent

Tags: percentages

I need to get the number between two numbers when input is percent.

I use this formula to get a percent between lets say $X = 450$, $A = 400$, $B = 500$ then $R$ will be $50$.

$R = \frac{X-A}{B-A}*100$

How do i find $X$ when only knowing $R$, $A$ and $B$?

If $A= 400$, $B = 500$, $R = 50$, then $X$ should output $450$. I never understand how to edit formulas..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$R(B-A)=100(X-A)$$
$$\Rightarrow X-A=\frac{R(B-A)}{100}$$
$$\Rightarrow X=\frac{R(B-A)}{100}+A$$
$$\Rightarrow X=\frac{RB+A(100-R)}{100}$$

Is this what you're looking for?